# how to Average for every 10 values of 8200x1 array in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have data in `.txt` format and successfully imported data to a variable V which is 8200x1 matrix. Now I need to get average for every 10 values. Can any one help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `colfilt`. You can take average every 10 values as: `[1,...,10]` then `[2,...,11]` then `[3,...,13]` etc. as follows:

```
a=randi(10,[8200 1]);
b=colfilt(a,[10 1],'sliding',@(x) mean(x))
```

If you want to average over distinct blocks of 10 values as: `[1,...,10]`,`[11,...,20]` etc., then just replace `'sliding'` with `'distinct'`.

You can do the same operation with `blockproc` and `nlfilter` but `colfilt` executes faster as stated in Mathworks `colfilt` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average of  each *separate* block of size 10: reshape into a 10-row matrix and then average each column:

```
n = 10;
result = mean(reshape(V, n, []), 1);
```

If you want the average on a *sliding* window of length 10: use convolution:

```
result = conv(V, ones(1,n)/n, 'valid');
```